# Polymorphism on c# property

Tags: c#, asp.net, polymorphism

I have a class like this:

```
public class ItemField
{

    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public object FieldValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I want to have it so that "FieldValue" can only be of type string, MyItem, or List<MyItem>. I also want it so that when code consumes this class, accessing "FieldValue" returns the right type of object. Is there a way to do this? I'm not too clear on generics, but there seems to be a way to do this using that...

Comment: I'm confused now: Should a single instance of `ItemField` always have the same type of `FieldValue`?

Comment: Yes - Basically, this class will hold data coming from a tree structure. So, sometimes, the tree structure will only have a string value. Other times, it will hold a sub-tree. I can also hold an item only has '1' node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property can only return one specific type, you can't make it return different data types depending on what the actual type of the field value is.

You can use generics for the class, but then you need to create the class instance for the type of data that you want to store in it:

```
public class ItemField<T> {

  public string FieldName { get; set; }

  public T FieldValue {
    get;
    set;
  }

}
```

Comment: I can do that, but how would I handle 'string' in this case?

Comment: You'd create a new instance: `var field = new ItemField<string>();`. That way, `field.FieldValue` would be of type `string` for that instance.

Comment: but then, I can put it any 'type' in T, right? I want to be able to restrict it - so there is a way to do something like where T : string, right?

Comment: @M.R.: You can't specify several distinct types with `where`. You can check the type in the constructor and throw an exception if it's not allowed, or you can make a private constructor and three static methods that create the three different types.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the client knows exactly what type of the field it gets, you can change the property definition into a function to use generics, like this:

```
private object fieldValue;

public T GetFieldValue<T>() {
    return (T)fieldValue;
}
```

The users must call this method like this:

```
MyItem item = itemField.GetFieldValue<MyItem>();
```

However, the cast is still there, and it is not clear how the users are expected to know what type to supply as the generic type parameter.

A better approach would be to use some sort of a double dispatch mechanism, for example, the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), to "invert" the direction and let your field "push" the value into the caller.

```
interface IItemFieldVisitor {
    void VisitString(string val);
    void VisitMyItem(MyItem val);
    void VisitList(IList<MyItem> val);
}

interface IItemField {
    string Name {get;set;}
    void Accept(IItemFieldVisitor visitor);
}

class StringItemField : IItemField {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    private string val;
    public void Accept(IItemFieldVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.VisitString(val);
    }
}

class MyItemItemField : IItemField {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    private MyItem val;
    public void Accept(IItemFieldVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.VisitMyItem(val);
    }
}

class MyItemListItemField : IItemField {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    private IList<MyItem> val;
    public void Accept(IItemFieldVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.VisitList(val);
    }
}
```

Now you can create instances of `IItemFieldVisitor` interface, and pass them to `IItemField` objects. The visitors will receive callbacks with specific values without knowing the type of the `IItemField` objects being visited.

Comment: The visitor pattern sounds interesting. Would you mind sharing some more details about it, in relation to how it applies here? I read the wiki, and conceptually the problem is similar, but I'm not entirely sure how I would apply it..

Comment: @M.R. I updated the answer with an example of a simplified visitor pattern, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reponse! I understand this better now, but how to would clients get the value from the fields?

Comment: @M.R. Clients would need to implement a visitor, and pass it to a field. The field would then call the client back on one of the three methods, passing the proper value. You would put different code inside different implementations of the visitor, depending on what needs to be done with the value.

Answer (score 1):

you could create your own abstract class 'Field' and have a string, MyItem or List derive from the 
abstract class. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_C_Sharp_Abstract_Classes

you can look into abstract class factory at this link: 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/Design-Patterns-Part-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you're not sure if you should be returning one item or a collection of items.  Rather than changing the return type dynamically (which is something you can't really do in a useful way) it would make more sense to just always return a collection.  That collection can always contain a single item if that's appropriate.

If you change the return type to `List<MyItem>` then most of the problems and bad code smell just go away.

Comment: that works for the second two cases, but it doesn't work for the cases when all I have to return is a string..

Comment: @M.R. In that case I would suggest finding a way to store the string in an instance of `MyItem`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know `string` is not used as generic constraint, take a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx):

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

So you can work around like this if you to constraint T as string

```
public class ItemField<T> where T :  ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public T FieldValue { get; set; }

}
```